# Adding Points totals from two different tables

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a point system and I'm trying to add them together. They are on two different tables and I'm using a subquery to get both totals and add them together. Both subqueries on their own work fine, but adding them together gives me a far greater number than it's supposed to.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT (SUM(tbl_achieve.achieve_points)+SUM(tbl_assign.assign_points))
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT(tbl_achievements.achieve_id), tbl_achievements.achieve_points FROM tbl_achievements INNER JOIN tbl_studentachieve ON tbl_studentachieve.achieve_id = tbl_achievements.achieve_id AND tbl_studentachieve.student_ID = 8 AND tbl_achievements.achieve_cat = "main" ) as tbl_achieve,

(SELECT DISTINCT(tbl_assignments.assign_id), assign_points FROM tbl_assignments INNER JOIN tbl_studentassign ON tbl_studentassign.assign_id = tbl_studentassign.assign_id WHERE tbl_assignments.assign_cat = "main" AND tbl_studentassign.student_id = 8 AND tbl_studentassign.assign_status = "submitted") as tbl_assign
```

I think what the problem is, is that it puts both row counts together. So instead of having 2 rows of 10 points, I have 10 rows of 10 points because of the other table's number.

Any idea what I could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

This one is going to be tough without knowing anything about your database. I ran the following query:
                 select SUM(feed_id) + SUM(user_id)  FROM events where 1

on my own db and it returns the correct addition of those complete rows together as only one row. It sounds like that is not what you want, but that is the expected behavior of mySQL. perhaps a more detailed explanation of what you're looking for would help to get you where you need to be. Cheers...